# AngularJS - ngRepeat by $index weirdness

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I am trying to implement an array (possible_parts) of objects and when an object is clicked add it to another array (warranty_parts). The trick is that the warranty_parts list can contain the same object more than once. I am using "track by $index" and everything works fine.

Then i need to inject another object (reason) to the selected part from warranty_part which I do with:

```
<select ng-model="selected_reason" ng-options="war.name for war in warranty_reasons"
ng-change="load_warranty_subreasons($index, part, selected_reason)">
```

And the function:

```
$scope.load_warranty_subreasons = function(index, part, reason){
    part.selected_reason = reason;
}
```

But when I do this, all the parts in warranty_parts get the reason selected for the last part which means that I somehow append the reason to the all the parts. I tried to append it via $index:

```
$scope.warranty_parts[$index].selected_reason = reason;
```

But I end up with the same result. I also tried $apply, I tried to generate random string and insert it into the part object so the objects are different but I keep getting the same result- the reason is appended to all the parts and not the only one i want.

Anyone can help me with this? I also tried:

```
ng-repeat="part in warranty_parts track by $index(part)"
```

But then I get an error message: number in not a function.

Thanks!

Comment: `$index` is actually number, not a function.

Comment: I do not question that.

Comment: Can we see a bit more of your html, where is part coming from? How do you populate warranty_parts? It is not clear your though process from what you've posted.

Comment: I think you need to post a larger chunk of your HTML, showing the ng-repeat to see where the part and reason sit in context to each other.